# Joomla modules file structure to store jquery core and some image files

Tags: php, joomla, module, filestructure

I'm a newbie to joomla. 
I'm trying to create a joomla module which uses some jquery actions and some image files.

Can anyone suggest me a best method to place the jquery-core and jquery plugin files inside the module. 
I also wants to add some image files with my module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include the JQuery you should use $document->addscript()

http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_JavaScript

You should be aware that it might conflict with Mootools already loaded so you might need to use the noconflict flag for jquery to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I might be not the best person for Joomla, but can't you just get your script in mod_[modulename].php file? Or I might now have understood your question.

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you use the manual script tag (`<script></script>`) to include your jQuery to avoid it conflicting with any other included scripts.

`$doc->addScript` will add the script to the head tag while manual inclusion will just place just above your module, which is much safer.